# Need to update UI message when user is sitting on a message that has just been put on hold

Tags: bug

While entering an answer to a question, the question was put on hold, and the UI updated to warn me that the question was CLOSED.  The text of this message is incorrect since now the question was only put on hold and will not be closed for a few days.  It should be edited to say "on hold" to be in line with the recent changes to the close workflow.

Comment: Closed is __the same__ as on hold, so "only put on hold" and "will not be closed for a few days" aren't quite accurate. This might be too much effort for what is a cosmetic change for the _OP's_ benefit.